# C format string

Tags: c, format-string

I have problem in this code. This is behaving so weirdly. please explain.

```
printf("CONTROLS:\nw , %c: up\n" 
        "a , %c: left\n" 
        "s , %c: down\n" 
        "d , %c: right\n" 
        "q , ESC: EXIT\n"
        ,24,27,25,26);
```

OUTPUT:

```
CONTROLS:
w , ↑: up
a ,  left
s , ↓: down
d , →: right
q , ESC: EXIT
```

I tried removing the colon after %c but it eats the 'l'

what is happening. I am interested in knowing the behind the scenes.

```
//this works:
 for(int ch=24;ch < 28;ch++) /* 27 = Esc key */
    {
        printf("%c:%d\n",ch,ch);

    }
```

Comment: @bitz-22, Do you realize you are attempting to print control characters including the Escape character (#27)?

Comment: First you got your codes in wrong order, second, ESC(27)+25 resulting in a control sequence to your terminal (not sure what exactly does it do, but definitely not what you would expect)

Comment: Alt Codes (what you're trying to use) are not the same as Ascii Codes (what `%c` expects)

Comment: They are non-printing characters, although the console might have some representation. Perhaps you can find Unicode characters for the arrows, or print "right-arrow" instead of trying to output "→ right". For the arrow, you might need to configure the console for Unicode.

Comment: Recommend [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)#Unicode) for a fix.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 4):

You are printing *non-printable* control characters. No glyphs are associated with those characters. They are meant to control the communication for various purposes, not to generate a glyph.

Now, your terminal happens to display arrows for some of the control characters it doesn't care about. But `27`—`1B` in hex—is actually meaningful to the terminal. It's used as the start of sequences that clear the screen, move the cursor, color the screen, etc.

Long story short, you are using the wrong Code Points. You are using

- U+0018 CANCEL
- U+0019 END OF MEDIUM
- U+001A SUBSTITUTE
- U+001B ESCAPE

There are Code Points that produce arrow glyphs, including

- U+2190 LEFTWARDS ARROW (←)
- U+2191 UPWARDS ARROW (↑)
- U+2192 RIGHTWARDS ARROW (→)
- U+2193 DOWNWARDS ARROW (↓)

You'll have to encode those appropriately for your terminal. That's probably UTF-8, so

- U+2190 LEFTWARDS ARROW (←): `E2 86 90`
- U+2191 UPWARDS ARROW (↑): `E2 86 91`
- U+2192 RIGHTWARDS ARROW (→): `E2 86 92`
- U+2193 DOWNWARDS ARROW (↓): `E2 86 93`

Comment: Universal character names can be used in string literals, integer character constants, and identifiers (with some caveats) since C99.  They provide a good way to not have to worry (much) about the terminal's character encoding. For example, `"\u2190"` for the leftward arrow.

Comment: @John Bollinger, Does that produce `char` (as opposed to some wide char)? If so, then the encoding would happen at compile-time, and might be incorrect. But then again, the way I suggested already presumes a UTF-8 terminal...

Comment: Universal character names are *lexical* units.  The implementation is responsible for doing appropriate things with them, according to the context in which they appear.  Specifically with `"\u2190"`, my interpretation is that the standard must interpret that as representing a nul-terminated static array of `char` containing a multibyte character representation of "LEFTWARD ARROW" in the implementation's runtime character set.  Can something go wrong with that?  Yes, of course.  But it's semantically correct, and less likely to cause trouble than is hardcoding UTF-8 sequences.

Comment: @John Bollinger, I wasn't suggesting hardcoding UTF-8 sequences. I was speaking of the output of the program. This is a job for wide characters. Well, that's assuming the clib stuff actually encode wide characters appropriately for the terminal. Honestly, I don't know much about C handles or mishandles Unicode. (I know its wide characters allowed to be too small for Unicode, which isn't a great start!)

Comment: You said "you're going to need to encode those for your terminal" and provided UTF-8 byte sequences, so I hope you understand how I took that as a recommendation to hardcode UTF-8.  And if UTF-8 is indeed the correct encoding for the environment then no, that's often *not* a job best suited for wide characters.  But universal character names can be used in wide strings too, so wide *vs* narrow is not a key distinction here.

Comment: @ohn Bollinger, Re "*And if UTF-8 is indeed the correct encoding for the environment*", You again assume that's known at compile-time, but it isn't. There's no "correct encoding for the environment" at compile-time, because the environment in question is run-time environement.

Comment: To whatever extent it is not known at compile time, @ikegami, it is the implementation's responsibility to handle that.  "Runtime character set" is a well-defined C concept that implementations are obligated to support.

Comment: @John Bollinger, Re "*it is the implementation's responsibility to handle that*", No, that's wrong. The sequence of bytes output of `printf( "%s\n", "\u20AC" )` is NOT suppose to change for different runs of the same executable.

Comment: I did not say that `printf` performed runtime transcoding.  Nor did I say that an implementation had to do transcoding in any more general sense, although I would argue that the spec's definition of "translation" is loose enough that such is, indeed, allowed.  Typically, though, implementations define the execution character set -- which need not be the same as the source character set -- at compile time.  However the implementation chooses, that is how it must interpret universal character names.  This is not particularly different from any other (possibly-multibyte) character.

Comment: So the alternatives here are: (i) perform a manual encoding of "LEFTWARDS ARROW" *et. al.* that you hope will work at run time and that you are obliged to modify if you turn out to need something different, or (ii) use universal character names that you can rely on the implementation to encode according to whatever it decides is the execution character set, the same as all other characters.  Operationally, you can be better off with the latter, but you are at least not worse off.  Semantically, universal character names are clearer.

Comment: aye. In Perl, you can use `"LEFTWARDS ARROW: \N{ LEFTWARDS ARROW }"`, and it's great.

Answer (score 3):

Your original code doesn't work out for a few reasons, but most notably because the `printf()` formatting is using `%c` ( for `char` ) and the codes ( 24, 27, 25, 26 ) given to the `%c` references in `printf()` do not align with the symbols you desire.

Here is some code that should work for you.  It uses [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)#Unicode) strings to get the results you want. Please also note the `printf()` formatting in this instance:  we use `%s` for strings instead of `%c` -- which is used for chars.

This code actually gives the output shown below, and the runnable version is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/v7e1rcE7o).

EDIT: In appreciation of John Bollinger's comment below -- and always finding better ways of doing things -- please note the code update for the `szUP` declaration: it uses the newer/proper Unicode coding now. The results are in fact, identical and the runnable code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/17c1WW9EG).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if 0
  char szUP[] = {0xE2, 0x86, 0x91, 0x00};
#else
  const char * const szUP = "\u2191";  /* Thx John B. */
#endif 
char szLT[] = {0xE2, 0x86, 0x90, 0x00};
char szDN[] = {0xE2, 0x86, 0x93, 0x00};
char szRT[] = {0xE2, 0x86, 0x92, 0x00};

int main()
{
printf("CONTROLS:\n"
        "w, %s: up\n" 
        "a, %s: left\n" 
        "s, %s: down\n" 
        "d, %s: right\n" 
        "q, ESC: EXIT\n",szUP,szLT,szDN,szRT);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    w, ↑: up
    a, ←: left
    s, ↓: down
    d, →: right
    q, ESC: EXIT
```

Comment: Supposing that one can rely at least on C99, universal character names have considerable advantage over hard-coding UTF-8.  For example, `const char * const szUP = "\u2191";`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- 100%.  I've updated the code for the world and credited you.   Thanks!